# How can I create a docker image with a initialized database

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to use the official [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) to create an new image with an initialized database and imported dump file. The default command is `mysqld`, so I wonder how I can achieve this.
Is there a way to only initialize the database and import a dump, without starting the mysql daemon?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL docker images automatically parse `.sh` `.sql` and `.sql.gz` from the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory on first start up. Files will be executed in alphabetical order.

Dump your existing database to a file, then edit your Dockerfile to add:

```
ADD mysqldump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysqldump.sql
```

On first start, `mysqldump.sql` will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to access the bash shell of the docker container (please see "Container shell access and viewing MySQL logs" section in https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ ), import your dump file (you can use `docker cp` to copy the dump file from your host system to the docker container) and once you are done, you can use `docker commit` command to create a new docker image from your current running container. And you can use the newly created image afterwards.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works, though I still don't like the process. I can't automate this, as far as I see.

Comment: You can also create a docker file in which you can mention the same steps and from that docker file you can create a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for `mysql:5.7`. I execute the slightly modified [entrypoint.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/mysql/0590e4efd2b31ec794383f084d419dea9bc752c4/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh) during the build process:

```
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN /docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
```

In the `docker-entrypoint.sh` I deleted the last line:

```
exec "$@
```

It looks ugly, but it works so far.